# How to get posted value from different function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3.1 .

How to return or get posted email after submit data from different function?

**HTML**

```php
<form action="settings/valid" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```php
public function index() {
    // how to get post email ? 
   $email = $this->input->post("email"));

   $this->template->loadContent("settings/index.php", array(
    "email" => $email
    )
    );

}

public function valid() {
    $email = $this->input->post("email"));

    $this->user->add($this->user->ID, array(
        "email" => $email
    ));

    redirect(site_url("index.php"));

}
```

Comment: You need to learn the basics first. Do the tutorial then all of this will be much clearer - http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may answer your question better.

```
public function index() {
    // how to get post email ? 
   $email = $this->session->flashdata("email");

   $this->template->loadContent("settings/index.php", array(
    "email" => $email
    )
    );

}

public function valid() {
    $email = $this->input->post("email"));

    $this->user->add($this->user->ID, array(
        "email" => $email
    ));

    $this->session->set_flashdata("email",$email);

    redirect(site_url("index.php"));

}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank You :)

Comment: Thank you. Can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238671/ajax-upload-not-working-codeigniter ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is called routing. That means that it makes no sense to get the email in index, because no data has been sent to index. What you can do is redirect the user to index and pass a post argument to index.

To put it another way. Let's say you open a web page and give it your name. You cannot expect another page to know your name as well, because that page does not exist yet (it has not been generated yet by php).

But you can send the user to another page and tell that page the user's name.

For instance, in your case:

in `valid()`

```
redirect(site_url("index.php?email=".$email));
```

and in `index()`

```
$email = $this->input->get("email")
```

Comment: when is index called ?

Comment: `http://localhost/settings/index` and post url `http://localhost/settings/valid` . After post return to index .

Comment: What I wrote should work, just replace `post` with `get` in `index()` and  `"index.php"` by `"index.php?email=".$email` in `valid()`

Comment: Hyy working but any way to hide the posted email from url?

Comment: I added another answer